Scanning an eicar.com file to test my AMSI code is breaking the code because of the eicar.com file
I have an implementation of the Windows Anti-Malware Scan Interface (AMSI) which I developed and want to use to scan files and check if they are safe from threats/viruses. I also created an eicar.com file which is supposed to be detected as an unsafe file by anti-viruses which I want to use to test my code and see if it gets deemed as unsafe (AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED). Only problem is that when I run the test method, I get this exception:
enter image description here
Which is concerning because it's supposed to be detected as a virus in the ScanFile() method of my AMSI scanner implementation (which I included in this post) instead of an exception.
This is my test method:
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ScanVirusFile()
        {
            bool success = false;
            string response = "Nothing happened.";
            try
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\Test\Source\eicar.com";
                AMSI_RESULT amsiResult = AmsiScan.ScanFile(filePath, "iCloudDx");
                if (amsiResult == AMSI_RESULT.AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED)
                {
                    success = false;
                    response = "Threats detected.";
                }
                else
                {
                    success = true;
                    response = "No threats detected.";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                success = false;
                response = ex.Message;
            }
            var result = new { Response = response };
            var httpResponse = Request.CreateResponse(success ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, result, "application/json");
            httpResponse.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            return httpResponse;
        }

This is my AMSI scanner implementation:
using DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.Commands.Internal;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ICloudDX_UI_Web.Helpers
{
    #region AMSI Result
    /// <summary>
    /// Enum storing the different outcomes of an AMSI Scan.
    /// </summary>
    public enum AMSI_RESULT
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// File is clean from malware.
        /// </summary>
        AMSI_RESULT_CLEAN = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// No threats detected in the file, but this does not mean its 100% clean.
        /// </summary>
        AMSI_RESULT_NOT_DETECTED = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// Threats detected.
        /// </summary>
        AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED = 32768
    }
    #endregion

    #region AMSI Scan
    /// <summary>
    /// Static class providing virus scan functionality using the Windows Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI).
    /// </summary>
    public static class AmsiScan
    {
        #region AMSI API Methods
        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiInitialize", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int AmsiInitialize([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string appName, out IntPtr amsiContext);

        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiUninitialize", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void AmsiUninitialize(IntPtr amsiContext);

        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiOpenSession", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int AmsiOpenSession(IntPtr amsiContext, out IntPtr session);

        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiCloseSession", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void AmsiCloseSession(IntPtr amsiContext, IntPtr session);

        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiScanString", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int AmsiScanString(IntPtr amsiContext, [InAttribute()][MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string @string, [InAttribute()][MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string contentName, IntPtr session, out AMSI_RESULT result);
        
        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", EntryPoint = "AmsiScanBuffer", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern int AmsiScanBuffer(IntPtr amsiContext, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] buffer, uint length, [In()][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string contentName, IntPtr session, out AMSI_RESULT result);

        [DllImport("Amsi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool AmsiResultIsMalware(AMSI_RESULT result);
        #endregion

        #region Scan Methods
        /// <summary>
        /// Check whether an AMSI Result indicates malware.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="amsiResult">The AMSI result you want to check.</param>
        /// <returns>True if result indicates malware.</returns>
        public static bool IsMalware(AMSI_RESULT amsiResult)
        {
            return AmsiResultIsMalware(amsiResult);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scan a file for threats/viruses.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePath">Path to the file.</param>
        /// <param name="appName">Name of the app requesting the scan.</param>
        /// <returns>AMSI result</returns>
        public static AMSI_RESULT ScanFile(string filePath, string appName)
        {
            IntPtr amsiContext;
            IntPtr session;
            AMSI_RESULT result = 0;
            int returnValue;

            byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            returnValue = AmsiInitialize(appName, out amsiContext);
            returnValue = AmsiOpenSession(amsiContext, out session);
            returnValue = AmsiScanBuffer(amsiContext, fileContent, (uint)fileContent.Length, Path.GetFileName(filePath), session, out result);
            AmsiCloseSession(amsiContext, session);
            AmsiUninitialize(amsiContext);

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scan a collection of files for threats/viruses.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filePaths">Paths of the files.</param>
        /// <param name="appName">Name of the app requesting the scan.</param>
        /// <returns>AMSI result</returns>
        public static AMSI_RESULT ScanFiles(string[] filePaths, string appName)
        {
            IntPtr amsiContext;
            IntPtr session;
            AMSI_RESULT result = 0;
            int returnValue;

            if (filePaths.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    byte[] fileContent = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                    returnValue = AmsiInitialize(appName, out amsiContext);
                    returnValue = AmsiOpenSession(amsiContext, out session);
                    returnValue = AmsiScanBuffer(amsiContext, fileContent, (uint)fileContent.Length, Path.GetFileName(filePath), session, out result);
                    AmsiCloseSession(amsiContext, session);
                    AmsiUninitialize(amsiContext);

                    if (result == AMSI_RESULT.AMSI_RESULT_DETECTED)
                        break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scan a folder for threats/virsses.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="folderPath">Path to the folder.</param>
        /// <param name="appName">Name of the app requesting the scan.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static AMSI_RESULT ScanFolder(string folderPath, string appName)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);

            IntPtr amsiContext;
            IntPtr session;
            AMSI_RESULT result = 0;
            int returnValue;

            if (filePaths.Length > 0)
            {
                result = ScanFiles(filePaths, appName);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scan a folder for threats/viruses.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="folderPath">Path to the folder.</param>
        /// <param name="filePattern">Specify a pattern to only scan certain kinds of files in the folder.</param>
        /// <param name="folderOption">Specify whether to scan all subfolders of the folder.</param>
        /// <param name="appName">Name of the app requesting the scan.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static AMSI_RESULT ScanFolder(string folderPath, string filePattern, SearchOption folderOption, string appName)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, filePattern, folderOption);

            IntPtr amsiContext;
            IntPtr session;
            AMSI_RESULT result = 0;
            int returnValue;

            if (filePaths.Length > 0)
            {
                result = ScanFiles(filePaths, appName);
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Scan a string (content) for threats/viruses.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="content">The string of content.</param>
        /// <returns>AMSI result</returns>
        public static AMSI_RESULT ScanContent(string content, string appName)
        {
            IntPtr amsiContext;
            IntPtr session;
            AMSI_RESULT result = 0;
            int returnValue;

            returnValue = AmsiInitialize(appName, out amsiContext);
            returnValue = AmsiOpenSession(amsiContext, out session);
            returnValue = AmsiScanString(amsiContext, content, "ScanString", session, out result);
            AmsiCloseSession(amsiContext, session);
            AmsiUninitialize(amsiContext);

            return result;
        }
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
}

I did manage to prevent this exception from occurring by excluding the eicar.com file from the Windows Defender quarantine and allowing it on my device, but after doing so, the scan returns a result of 'AMSI_RESULT_NOT_DETECTED' which means that it did not detected any threats with the file. This is obviously a concern since its supposed to be detected as a threat, but I have a feeling, that allowing it on the device in Windows Defender is causing it to not be detected as a threat since AMSI scans the file using Windows Defender and in Windows Defender I declared it as 'safe'.
